# How to pass the value from a dynamically created table into a new database query using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So far I've created a table from a database query using the input from a dropdown menu. Now I want the user to be able to click on a cell in that table and using the the value of that cell query the database again for further information. Here's what I have:

```
echo "
<tr>
<td>".$value['Time']."</td>
<td><a href='#'><div value=".$value['First_Name'].">".$value['First_Name']."</div></a></td>
...
```

This continues on for the rest of the information but thats the code for my initial table. The user should then click on First_Name for further information provided by an AJAX request. My jQuery so far looks like this...I haven't even been able to start the AJAX as I can't pass in the value of the table cell.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tables').on('click','td', function(){
            var module= $(this).val();
            alert(module);
        })
```

Once I figure out how to pass this value then I can move ahead with the database query but this is holding me back. Do I even need to do this if Im using JQuery AJAX? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `var module= $(this).html();`

Comment: @hakJav no that just returned the full html for me but .text() is what I needed. It returns what I need so thanks, your comment led me down the right path. I still feel that I should be able to do it the right way though and return the value rather than the text.

Comment: Coolio - if you're after the `value=""` data, then you can use `var module= $(this).find("div").attr("value");` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want get the text inside the element tag. Please use `.text()` not `.val()`
example:

`var module= $(this).text();`

I hope this usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to bind click event on `<a>` instead of `<td>`. That will work good too.

Now question is you want to pass some value through **AJAX** to **PHP** script. Good practice to do this is by setting [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes to `<a>` element.

So your **HTML/PHP** code will look something like this,

```
<td>".$value['Time']."</td>
<td><a href='#' class='myLink' data-modelvalue='".$value['First_Name']."'><div value=".$value['First_Name'].">".$value['First_Name']."</div></a></td>
```

In above code we've given a class to `<a>` to bind click event on each element having this class. (Useful for multiple records generated using loop), we have also set **data-modelvalue** attribute to `<a>`.

Now update your jQuery code like this,

```
$('#tables').on('click','.myLink', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var module= $(this).data('modelvalue');
     alert(module);
});
```

In above code we have bind click event on **myLink** class elements. Also we're fetching **data-modelvalue** using [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) jQuery method.

**e.preventDefault()** forces default action of the event to not be triggered, in our case page won't get refreshed(which is default action of any hyperlink).

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
https://api.jquery.com/data/
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/